# Itering and compare struct element with different size

Tags: c, loops, struct, unions, x-macros

I've a tricky question and I don't know if there is any solution.

Basically I've populated a struct using x-macros, for example with the following macro:

```
#define X_MACRO_TABLE(_) \
_(var_1 , type1)\
_(var_2, type2)\
_(...., ....)\
_(var_n, type_n)\
```

I can have an output like that:

```
    typedef struct __attribute__((packed, aligned(1)))
    {
        union {
            struct __attribute__((packed, aligned(1))) data{
                type_1 var_1;
                type_2 var_2;
                ....
                type_n var_n;
            }data_s;
            uint8 DataArray[sizeof(struct data)];
        };
    }data_t;
```

It is something I often do and it's works fine.

Now let's say I need to define two struct:

```
static data_t   DataVar;
static data_t   DataVar_max;
```

There is any way using a loop or something to compare each element of the struct with its maximum?

```
DataVar.var_1 > DataVar_max.var_1 ??
DataVar.var_2 > DataVar_max.var_2 ??
```

Or passing through the array, due to the fact I know the types dimension, for example in case var_1 is equal to uint16_t do something like:

```
(DataVar.DataArray[0]+DataVar.DataArray[1]<<8) > (DataVar_max.DataArray[0]+DataVar_max.DataArray[1]<<8) ??
```

Comment: Do you mean how to create such a loop using the existing X macro code? Obviously you can create a loop without the macros, so why can't you do that?

Comment: I don't get how to create a loop inside such a struct. Can you explain me please?

Comment: Either write a plain old for loop and ignore that the code was generated with X macros. Or alternatively use the X macros for a loop unrolling kind of call as in my posted answer, which will expand just as an unrolled loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the types can be compared with the `>` operator and both structs are initialized, you can simply do:

```
#define COMP_MEMBERS(name, type) if (DataVar.name > DataVar_max.name) { do_something(); }
...
X_MACRO_TABLE(COMP_MEMBERS)
```

This will expand to an `if` statement per member.

Comment: That's a good idea but unfortunately it doesn't work since I need to concatenate the variable name. Like this: #define COMP_MEMBERS(name, type) if (DataVar.##name > DataVar_max.##name) { do_something(); }
...
X_MACRO_TABLE(COMP_MEMBERS) and the error is the following: "error: pasting "DataVar_max" and "'.'" does not give a valid preprocessing token" because the "." is already a token

Comment: @buch Concatenate the variable name with what? That example doesn't make sense, and you also need helper macros to expand the macro parameters before concatenation.